# display new line every day form text file automatically

Tags: php

I have a text file that I want to read a new line from it every day 
how can I update the start and the end value every day automatically?

```php
$start = 1; // array indexes are starting with zero
$end = 4;   // array indexes are starting with zero

$lines = file('test.txt'); // get lines of file as an array
for($i = $start; $i <= $end && $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i];
}
```

Comment: So you want to fetch line 1 the first day, line 2 the second day, and so on?

Comment: yes. the code is working fine but I need a solution to do it automatically :)

Comment: Are you willing to change the layout of the text file? What is the current layout?

Comment: the layout is simple text file no HTML or CSS just text. I need to change the start and the end values every day

Comment: Just read the file into array, display the first line, delete the first line from array. Write back the array to file

Comment: as you can see it is already in an array my problem is to do it automatically every day

Comment: Either set a cron job or write some code that includes the file in every web visit. In the last case you have to store the modifying date too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have to read the file for every visitor to display the first line of the text, you can write a bit of code to modify the file if needed.

Suppose you have this file:

```
2019-05-12
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

Then include this piece for every visitor:

```
$text = file('myfile.txt');      // read file into array
$date = $text[0];                // get the last update date
$now = date('Y-m-d',time());     // today
$show = 1;                       // 1 = first text line in array

//if we need to update
if( $date !== $now ){
     $show = 2;                  // 2 = we need a new line
     $text[0] = $now;            // set last update to today
     unset($text[1]);            // delete the old line
     // write back file without the deleted line
     file_put_contents('myfile.txt', implode("\n",$text); 
}

echo $text[$show];
```

Not tested the code, but you get the idea

Comment: No problem. Make sure you build in some error trapping for the case when there are no more lines in the file :-)